# How Gaussian Quadreture deals with improper integral.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gaussian-integers

What I know, any integral can be transformed into a different function and weighted factor in Gaussian-Quadreture method. The the limit is [-1, 1].

But let assume we have an integral, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

If we change this integral to a Gaussian Quadrature, how will I deal the the value of **x=1**, I'm saying this because for, x=1 we get undetermined form. Even we change the integral, where does the improper  portion go?

I mean, I f we change any integral to  Gaussian Quadrature   integral form, how do we know that  we aren't dealing with the pole of the integral anymore?

Comment: For this particular example the pole at $x=1$ is not integrable. A better example to use is $1/\sqrt{1-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a [table of Gaussian quadrature abscissas](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html). Do you see $x = 1$ in any of them?

In fact it's a theorem that the abscissas of the Gauss-Legendre quadrature are the zeros of the Legendre polynomials, which lie strictly in the region $(-1, 1)$.

So endpoint singularities do not invalidate Gaussian quadrature rules, though they can become inaccurate. A bigger deal is that $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is poorly approximated by polynomials, so Gaussian quadrature is a poor choice.